# Is it possible to work with DOM of the loaded document

Tags: jquery, html

Is it possible to get access to file.html's DOM I’ve opened with jQuery in the following manner:

```
generateVocabulary() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "file.html",
        success: function (result) {
            // Some actions with file.html DOM here
            // to get into the main document just what I need
        }
    });
}
```

I need to count number of specific tags in external document and get innerHTML of some specific tags. May be there are some other ways?

Comment: ofcourse `result` contains the html do whatever u want with it

Comment: you can wrap string result in a jquery object and then use any kind of transversal method

Comment: I can get all <p> elements in my own document by something like this: $("p"). But how can I get all <p> elements in my result variable? Something like this: $(result)("p")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do something like:

```
$.ajax({url:"file.html",success:function(result){
    var dom = $(result);
    console.log(dom.find("someselector").length);
    dom.find("someselector").html("something else");
}});
```